# How to close Angular UI Modal from anywhere

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-service

I am using the [Angular UI bootstrap modal dialog](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) and create it within a service:

```
myApp.factory('ModalService', ['$modal', function($modal) {
    return {
        trigger: function(template) {
            $modal.open({
                templateUrl: template,
                size: 'lg',
                controller: function($scope, $modalInstance) {
                    $scope.ok = function() {
                        $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
                    };
                    $scope.cancel = function() {
                        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                    };
                }
            });
        },
        close: function() {
            // this should close all modal instances
        }
    };
}]);
```

How can I close all modal instances when calling `ModalService.close()` from a controller or whatsoever?

Comment: I am very appreciative for this post.  I was able to refactor my code through it.  Only difference is that i did use the resolve method that was similar to the docs to get data I was updating.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Inject the `$modalStack` service and call the function `$modalStack.dismissAll()`, see the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js#L287) for details:

```
myApp.factory('ModalService', ['$modal', '$modalStack' function($modal, $modalStack) {
    return {
        trigger: function(template) {
            $modal.open({
                templateUrl: template,
                size: 'lg',
                controller: function($scope, $modalInstance) {
                    $scope.ok = function() {
                        $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
                    };
                    $scope.cancel = function() {
                        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                    };
                }
            });
        },
        close: function(reason) {
            $modalStack.dismissAll(reason);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! I don't know why this is not mentioned in the docs https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal/docs

Comment: @DonJuwe agreed, would be helpful like when closing a modal on $http success.

Comment: Thanks very much, 
their help was very important. +1  =)

Comment: Awesome. It also works with AngularUI, just use `$uibModalStack`.

Comment: add comma in function arguments

Answer (score 1):

I added the below line to prevent browser back button routing and closing the popup. We need to inject $modalStack into angular controller.

```
event.preventDefault();
            $modalStack.dismissAll('close');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i got it working in my project without using any factory or additional code.

```
  //hide any open $mdDialog modals
  angular.element('.modal-dialog').hide();
  //hide any open bootstrap modals
  angular.element('.inmodal').hide();
  //hide any sweet alert modals
  angular.element('.sweet-alert').hide();
```

I have a timeout function that emits logout as `$rootScope.$emit('logout');` and the listener in my service is as follows:

```
$rootScope.$on('logout', function () {
                    //hide any open $mdDialog modals
                    angular.element('.modal-dialog').hide();
                    //hide any open bootstrap modals
                    angular.element('.inmodal').hide();
                    //hide any sweet alert modals
                    angular.element('.sweet-alert').hide();

                    //do something else here  

                });
```

I don't know if this is the right approach , but it works for me.