# Refactor angular bootstrap ui modal to a factory

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am working on refactoring the current code that I have.  My controller is beginning to become unmanageable.  I am working off of ui bootstrap.  I found a post similar to what I am doing [How to close Angular UI Modal from anywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445949/how-to-close-angular-ui-modal-from-anywhere)

Here is the factory function where I am making the connection to my database.  I am identifying it in the success of the modal controller

```
function updateDrink(id,payload){
// need a payload for put and for post
return $http.put('/api/drink/'+id,payload).
  success(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  }).
  error(function(data){
    console.log('error');
  });
```

}

**Here is my original code.  I put all of this inside of a controller Everything works fine.  I have the modal working I am getting the data.**

```
$scope.modalUpdate = function(size,selectedDrink) {
console.log(selectedDrink);

  var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
    templateUrl: 'templates/editCaffeineDrink.html',
    controller: function($scope,$modalInstance,drink,DrinkLibrary,Drink){
      $scope.drink = drink;

      $scope.ok = function(id){
          DrinkLibrary.updateDrink(id,$scope.drink).
          success(function(data){
          console.log(data);
        });
          $modalInstance.close($scope.drink);
    };

      $scope.cancel = function(){
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
      };
    },
  size: size,
    resolve: {
            // resolve the drink
      drink: function () {
              // return selected drink
          return selectedDrink;
      }
    }
});
  // end of mal instance/modal open

modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
},  function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
};
```

This is my click handler I am calling the modal update and am correctly updating my database with each click.

```
<a href="" ng-click="modalUpdate('lg',drink)">
    <i style="font-size:18px;" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
</a>
```

Here is my current factory. I am getting the modal to drop down and the correct data is shown.  However, I am not updating my information.

```
app.factory('ModalService', ['$modal', '$modalStack',function($modal, $modalStack) {
return {
  trigger:function(selectedDrink){
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
          templateUrl: 'templates/editCaffeineDrink.html',
          controller: function($scope,$modalInstance,drink,DrinkLibrary,Drink){
          $scope.drink = drink;
              $scope.ok = function(id){
                DrinkLibrary.updateDrink(id,$scope.drink).
                success(function(data){
                console.log(data);
              });
                $modalInstance.close($scope.drink);               };

              $scope.cancel = function(){
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
          },
          size: 'lg',
          resolve: {
                // resolve the drink

              drink: function () {
                return selectedDrink;
              }
          }
      });
      // end of modal open
  }
};
}]);
```

Inside of my controller I am calling the factory and trigger

```
  $scope.update=ModalService.trigger;
```

**Then on my click handler I am update on click and passing the object.  Everything is showing up in the modal but the modal is not updating.**

```
 <a href="" ng-click="update(drink)">
    <i style="font-size:22px;" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
 </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything actually worked on the code above.  I had some issues with nodemon not doing an update for me.  Besides the link I posted above I also got some of the idea out of the 30 day mean stack challenge through Bossable.