# How to close an Angular-ui-bootstrap uibModal on mouseleave using Factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, angularjs-service

I've recently switched all our modals directives in our app over to Angular-ui-Bootstrap modals. Much better, however running into a new style of modal which closes on mouseleave instead of a cancel click.

```
this.leaveTag = (tag) => {
    TagHover.off();
};

this.hoverTag = (tag) => {
    TagHover.display();
};
```

Above is the view logic that calls functions inside of our TagHover Factory.

Below is the Factory, the TagHover.display works fine like with our other modals, but what I'm trying to do with the `leaveTag > TagHover.off` is call the modal.close. Not working so far.

My question is how do you call the close functionality within the TagHoverController, or `close` on the $uibModal from my tagsPanel component -> TagsHover Factory? (Without using $scope or $rootScope events)

I'm not trying to call `close/cancel` from within the TagHover Ctrl scope, but trying to call `close` from a Parent scope.

```
const TagHover = angular.module('tickertags-shared')
    .controller('TagHoverController', TagHoverController)
    .factory('TagHover', factory);

TagHoverController.$inject = [
    'TagHover'];

function TagHoverController(
    TagHover) {

    this.$onInit = () => {
        console.log('TagHover onInit')
    };

    this.cancel = () => this.$close();
}

factory.$inject = ['$uibModal'];

function factory($uibModal) {

    const display = () => {
        const modal = $uibModal.open({
            controllerAs: 'tghov',
            bindToController:true,
            templateUrl: 'tags/tag_hover.html',
            windowClass: 'dash-modal',
            resolve: {},
            controller: 'TagHoverController'
        });
    };

    const off = () => {
        $uibModal.close({});
    };

    return {
        display,
        off
    }
}

module.exports = TagHover;
```

[image]

Here are the docs https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

> The open method returns a modal instance, an object with the following properties:
>
> close(result) (Type: function) - Can be used to close a modal, passing a result.

I also logged out the `$uibModal` object and I only see an open function, no close :(

[image]

Comment: Use $uibModalInstance.close() instead of $uibModal.close()

Comment: Hmm, I just tried that... I injected `$uibModalInstance` but got Unknown provider :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is wrong approach - you can not "just close modal", cause you dont tell which modal to close. I recommend you to redesign this...

You can have a look at `$uibModalStack` - it stores opened modals and have methods like `dismisAll`

Comment: Nice! This is working, I don't see any documentaion on `$uibModalStack` though, do you have a link?

Comment: This might be the solution, I found more info here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445949/how-to-close-angular-ui-modal-from-anywhere

Answer (score 11):

In your case, Your are using Factory for dynamic Modal. so you can use `$uibModalStack` in the below two ways.

1. `$uibModalStack.dismissAll(); // dismiss all opened modal`
2. `$uibModalStack.dismiss(openedModal.key); // dismiss modal by key`

#### Example of dismiss Method.

```
var top = $uibModalStack.getTop();
if (top) {
    $uibModalStack.dismiss(top.key);
}
```

> It's very important to do dismissing the modal during router changes since its dynamic modal.

In general, `$uibModal` will help to open the modal then each modal is  `$uibModalInstance`, if you want to close modal inside the modal.

#### Opening Modal on Event

```
angular.module('myPage')
  .controller('PageController', ['$uibModal',
    function($uibModal) {
      function onModalLink() {
        $uibModal.open({
          templateUrl: 'app/modals/paymentTpl.html',
          controller: 'PaymentModalController as vm',
          windowClass: 'generalModal myModal'
        });
      }
    }
  ]);
```

### To Close from Instance.

```
angular.module('paymentModal')
  .controller('PaymentModalController', [
    '$uibModalInstance',
    function ChangeRepaymentController($uibModalInstance) {
      function onCancel() {
        $uibModalInstance.close(repaymentPercentage);
      }
    }
  ]);
```

> `modalInstance` - The modal instance. This is the same $uibModalInstance injectable found when using controller.

WIKI Reference: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal/docs

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to close from the Modal, but from the Factory that set it up. I can just call this.cancel if I'm in the Modal's scope.

Comment: gotcha. you need to use $uibModalStack since its factory with detailed examples

Comment: Actually I need to revisit this now... I have to be able to target the specific modal that was opened, not all modals. In your example where is `repaymentPercentage` coming from?

Comment: Could you post another code example using my `function factory($uibModal)` example above? I'm trying to figure out how to set a modal key as well as call something by it's `openedModal.key`

Comment: Added the example for `$uibModalStack.dismiss`

Answer (score 5):

I use close() method with $uibModal and open() method for manage in AngularJS $uiModal

Open method

```
vm.lanzarPopShowTask = lanzarPopShowTask;
function lanzarPopShowTask(index){
    vm.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title-top',
        ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body-top',
        templateUrl: '/btask/index/task.html',
        size: 'm',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            vm.task = vm.tasks[index];
            vm.index = index;
        },
        scope: $scope
    });
}
```

And Close method

```
vm.modalInstance.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

When doing this I set the modal as a scope variable then use `$scope.sweetModal.close()` or `$scope.sweetModal.dismiss()` you just have to remember that if you were to do the following it wouldn't work:

```
$scope.openModal = function () {
    $scope.sweetModal = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: '/modals/sweetModal.html',
        size: 'md',
        scope: $scope,
        backdrop: true
    })
        .result.then($scope.modalCloseFunction, $scope.modalDismissFunction);
};
```

Where as the following would work because of how the variable is set:

```
$scope.openModal = function () {
    $scope.sweetModal = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: '/modals/sweetModal.html',
        size: 'md',
        scope: $scope,
        backdrop: true
    });

    $scope.sweetModal.result.then($scope.modalCloseFunction, $scope.modalDismissFunction);
};
```